# Difficulty in understanding Static in Java

Tags: java, static

**Class Stat1.java**

```
package Static;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale.Category;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Stat1 {
    static TreeSet<String> category= new TreeSet<>();;

    public static void main(String[]args){
        Stat1 s0 = new Stat1();
        s0.category.add("Pocket Money");
        s0.category.add("Salary");
        Stat1 s = new Stat1();
        s.category.add("Mother");
        s.print_Category();

        Stat1 s1 = new Stat1();
        s1.category.add("Father");
        s1.category.add("aaaaaaaa");
        Stat1.category.add("999");
        s1.print_Category();

    }

    public static void print_Category(){
        System.out.println(category);
    }
}
```

When I run the above class the output is-

```
[Mother, Pocket Money, Salary]
[999, Father, Mother, Pocket Money, Salary, aaaaaaaa]
```

**Class Stat2.java**

```
package Static;
import Static.Stat1;
public class Stat2 {
    public static void main(String[]args){

        Stat1 s = new Stat1();

        s.category.add("brother");
        System.out.println(s.category);


    }
}
```

Output is:

`[brother]`
Now According to my understanding **when we use static keyword then each object shares the same copy of that instance** which is evident in Stat1.java class.But in Stat2.java the output shows only the String that was added to the TreeSet in that Class only.
According to me the output should consist of all the elements that are added to the TreeSet.
Please explain what is done wrong.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What do you think `new Stat1();` does? Why do you think so?

Comment: Since static members belong to class and not instances you should access them via `ClassName.staticMember`. If you use `reference.staticMember` compiler will use type of `reference` and will still compile it into `ClassName.staticMember`. So all your `s0.category` are compiled as `Stat1.category`. So try to avoid `reference.staticMember` since it cause only confusion because you may think that you are accessing *instance* field rather than *class* field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the output should consist of all the elements that are added to the TreeSet.

I'm assuming you **expected** the output of Stat1 and Stat2 to be like this:

```
$ java -cp . Stat1
[Mother, Pocket Money, Salary]
[999, Father, Mother, Pocket Money, Salary, aaaaaaaa]

$ java -cp . Stat2
[999, Father, Mother, Pocket Money, Salary, aaaaaaaa, brother]
                                                      ^^^^^^^ 
    "brother" included after running Stat1 then Stat2 |
```

The reason you're only seeing `brother` after running Stat2 is because you are starting a brand new process.  **The `static` keyword only affects how data is shared within a single process**.

For instance, if you have a single java program in the file `myprog.jar`, and you run it twice

```
java -jar myprog.jar &
java -jar myprog.jar
```

then each one of those commands starts a new process.  Even though they are the *same program* running with the *same classes*, they do *not* share memory, so they do *not* share any instances of classes.  Even if `myprog.jar` uses static fields in classes, those classes have no idea about each other.

(So what does `static` actually do for you?  [Here](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java/java-for-beginners-static-variables-what-are-they.html) is an easy, example-driven description.)

**Solution:** If you want data to be shared across different processes, then you need to read and write to a database or a file so that the data lives after the process dies.  This is called [persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science)).

**Theory:** If you want to know more about what databases and files are doing for your programs when they are used in this way, read about [inter-process communicantion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

**Advanced:** If you want to use "the same" objects (i.e. objects with the same data) between different processes, learn about [object relational mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), which is a technology that automatically uses files/databases to synchronize objects across processes.  But I suggest practicing more with java and with files before attempting any of that.

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding a few things here.

First, the `static` keyword applies in several contexts, but let's focus on your case.  If it's attached to a field, then the value of the field is shared among instances of the class.  In other words, if you have multiple instances of a class, those instances will all reference the same field.

This is the scenario you exhibit in your first case; since you create more than one instance of `Stat1`, each instance has the same `TreeSet`, which is why you see more values added to it when you print the second time.

This is *also* why you're not seeing the same behavior in your second example.  Since you've only created *one* instance of `Stat1`, the static variable only holds the *one* value.

You're only executing one program at a time (which means you're only executing *one* of those cases at a time), so the behavior you were hoping to see in your second class won't materialize unless you instantiate more `Stat1` classes inside of `Stat2`.

Comment: _unless you instantiate more Stat1 classes in main_ What will this do? Do you mean the `main` in `Stat2` of `Stat1`? They're just creating instances. They're not modifying `category` from anywhere else when running `Stat2` as a program.

Comment: No, I mean to say that output of Stat2.java should be [999, Father, Mother, Pocket Money, Salary, aaaaaaaa,brother]

Comment: @user3774720:  It's not going to be since you're only executing one program.  Once `Stat1` concludes running, Java terminates and all state is lost.

Comment: I don't see why you keep referring to instances of `Stat1`. Those are irrelevant. It doesn't matter how many of those they create.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis:  Inside of `Stat2`, it is relevant.  That dictates how many things ultimately end up in the shared set.

Comment: One of us is missing something. `category` is a `static` field. They are trying to access it through an object reference. Why would more instances of `Stat1` make any difference?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis:  I've not recently had the time.  Give me some time and I'll get around to it.

Answer (score 1):

When You run second class java doesn't know nothing about first. 
If You write `s.main(null);`in your second class all strings will be in the set.